# How do I detect if a key is pressed without using a TextBox?

Tags: c#, keypress

I have looked on Stack Overflow and Google but I have yet to find an answer to my question. I want to detect when a key is pressed without the need of a text box.

Comment: Can you give us more details? Are you programming in ASP.Net or creating a console program or what? What other controls are available to you?

Comment: If its winforms you can use `Form.KeyPressed` or something.

Comment: @melanie when you see these kind of questions that don't specify the UI framework they're using you have to immediately assume its winforms. winforms developers have no idea other UI technologies exist (otherwise they wouldn't be using winforms to begin with).

Comment: HighCore - I'm smiling

Comment: This question can be closed as "Needs Clarity".

Answer (score 1):

Override `OnKeyPress` main `Form`, this will catch the key presses

Winforms:

```
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
```

WPF: (will have to use `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyUp`

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All controls (including forms) have the `KeyPress`, `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events that you may use.

- [`KeyPress` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)
- [`KeyDown` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx)
- [`KeyUp` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx)

And there are corresponding `OnKeyPress`, `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` methods that you can override in your own controls.